# What technique I should use now?

Tags: sudoku

I am stuck here. I don't want solution for this, I just want to know the name of technique which will be used here to go ahead.

[image: 1]

Comment: Well, the first technique I noticed seems to be referred to as ["Y-Wing Strategy"](https://www.sudokuwiki.org/Y_Wing_Strategy) at sudokuwiki.org.

Answer (score 4):

There's a big list of techniques [here](https://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm), and this one can be solved with:

> a Y-Wing at R5C6 (R5C3 and R7C6 force R7C3 to be 8), or use R7C6 as the base, with R7C3 and R5C6 as the wings to force R5C3.